# Hangman: Remember Previous Guesses

Tags: java

I am quite new Java so this might sound silly. 
 
I am trying to create a GUI based Hangman Game from Java. I've created list of buttons from array and it returns the individual letter as character when clicked. I have got list of Words to guess and every time a button is pressed it needs to compare the word with the pressed letter and replace if it matches.

A friend of mine suggested using an array to split and check letters but I'm not familiar with those stuffs. As I need to keep track of wrong input as well as count errors, I am not sure if it is the best idea to use the StringBuilder. If StringBuilder is the best option for me please help me with the problem below:

```
 String word = retWord; // The actual word  
 String s = "" + guessed; //Changing guessed letter to string 
 StringBuilder gletters = new StringBuilder(s);  
 String mainword = word.replaceAll("[^" + gletters + "]", "_"); //Replacing the matching letters  
 a.setText(mainword);
```

The code is performed inside `FOR` loop of button press, but the output needs to be 'apple'. Every time at button press the output looks something like this:

**When A is pressed :**A _ _ _ _
**When P is pressed :**_ p p _ _
**When L is pressed :**_ _ _ L _
**When E is pressed :**_ _ _ _ E

**My question is** how am I supposed to make it remember previous guesses that were correct, not just the current one?
Also how can I count errors for wrong button presses?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store previously guesses letters using an array of booleans.

```
boolean lettersGuessed = new boolean[26];
```

From there, take the letter pressed (a char, not a String) and convert it to upper case; then subtract 65. Use the number you get as the location in the array, and check to see if it was already guessed; if not set the entry there to true and either show the correct letters, or add 1 to the count of incorrect guesses.

The code for conversion to uppercase could look like:

```
// See if a lower case letter was entered
// Convert it to uppercase
if (guessed >= 97 && guessed <= 122) guessed -= 32;

// Subtract 65 to get array index
guessed -= 65;

// Make sure the guess is a letter
if (guessed <= 0 && guessed <= 25) {
    if (lettersGuessed[guessed]) {
        // The user already guessed this letter, do nothing
    } else {
        lettersGuessed[guessed] = true;
        // See if the letter guessed was right, if it was show the letters
        // If it wasn't, incorrectGuesses+1
}
```

The key idea this uses is that internally, computers use a number to represent letters (in this case, look up ascii values); knowing this we can work with these numbers to shift them into a range (0 to 25) that would work for locations in an array.

For checking if a letter was correct, you could do something like this (which is not the best way, but should be simple enough):

```
boolean correct = false;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) == guessed) {
        correct = true;
    }
}
```

After that runs, if the letter guessed is a letter in the word, `correct` will be true. Otherwise `correct` will be false.

For remembering previous guesses, instead of `String s = "" + guessed;`, where you redeclare String s each time, instead just declare String s once. Then, to add a letter to the end of it, use `s.concat("" + guessed)`.

Comment: This is overly complex, especially for someone who is new to java.

Comment: Maybe it is overly complex for someone new to java, but maybe it will give them ideas. That and you already gave a fine solution for using an ArrayList, so this is an alternative.

Comment: For checking with the default word, you could just look at the letter guessed and compare it to the letters in the word. If any letter matches, then the guess was correct. If no letters match, then the guess was incorrect.

Comment: Um I surely have got some idea on ASCII as I've used ASCII to create buttons and receive it's value hence I don't need to bother about checking for Case-Sensitiveness and I've disabled every button so the user pressing the same button twice ain't problem at all So i need to check if it's right or wrong only... So thanks for your help
I'll definitely try this one
So that's my answer to error count...
I wonder if you've got solution to my first question too ( Every time the word is checked with default word.)
And thanks again for your help

Comment: @Sammy I added a bit at the end for remembering previous guesses. Only create `String s` once, then add guessed letters to the end of it.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for your help 
and sorry if I'm being annoying but I suppose you're suggesting me to declare the guessed outside the for loop and append it inside for loop but I'm afraid that I cant do that because the value that is stored inside guessed are from button press which is created from for loop (Using Ascii and returning value using for loop) hence every time I press any letters button the for loop executes and it cant be helped...

Comment: You can't declare `String s` as part of the class, then initialize it to "" when the game starts? The value of `guessed` still comes from the button presses, you're just adding it to the end of `s` (which is declared outside of the for loop). So I'm suggesting you declare `String s` outside the for loop; `guessed` is fine where it is.

Comment: OK now i'm getting Exception java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 2
[^]

Comment: Before running the code for StringBuilder and calling replaceAll(), add a check for s.length() > 0. If there are no guessed letters, there are no characters after the ^ character; just replace all characters with an _. Or make sure you add the guessed letter to `s` before the StringBuilder gets created.

Comment: Thanks man it's working like charm after slight modifications to code
I really appreciate your help :D
I'll make sure I'll let you play one after it's completed

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help =) If you're done with this topic, go ahead an accept an answer and it will no longer show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Save the previously guessed letters in an Array

```
ArrayList<String> lettersGuessed;
```

Some pseudo code

```
When button pressed then
    added letter to list of letters guessed
    if the letter guessed is wrong then
        increment wrong guesses count
        end game it too many wrong guesses
    end if
    reveal all letters in the list of letters guessed
end when
```

Comment: Am I supposed to store 
<i> String mainword = word.replaceAll("[^" + gletters + "]", "_");</i>
the main word into arraylist after this code 
Sorry but I'm just new to java

Comment: @MattBall no reason, I typically default to using ArrayList but Set<String> would work just as well.

Comment: @Sammy try a for loop that calls your replace function for each of the letters in the list of letters guessed

Comment: @Sammy Try googling "java hangman" there are several examples of code for doing this. This is one is well commented: https://gist.github.com/mattbarackman/4137901

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you keep overwriting `gletters` with the for loop. This means that your regular expression overwrites everything except for the **new** guessed letter and not the previous ones, too.

To change as little code as possible (i.e. using `StringBuilder`), just initialize `gletters` outside of the for loop (with a capacity of at least the size of the correct word). Then inside the loop, just append to it.

You should be able to figure it out from here. JavaDocs are your friend! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: I tried to do the exact same thing as you've said previously and it didn't allow me to use it because it needs to be worked out using action listener and When is declared static inside main method it gave me Bunch of exceptions...

Comment: No action listener should be needed... Post more of your code to the original question so maybe I/others can see why that's happening.

Comment: OK, i'm creating these list of buttons using ASCII Values and it has been created using for loop hence for every button press I need to use action listeners in for loop to fetch it's value

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I'm assuming the ActionListener does something every time the user types a character. You're gonna have to do some restructuring then, it sounds like. `Main` should probably just initialize whatever class implements `ActionListener` with the correct word and maybe give the initial letter prompt. From there, the `ActionPerformed` should act on class instance variables to do what I said and then give the next prompt. In this case, `gletters` is initialized in the class constructor (for whatever implements ActionListener).

Answer (score 0):

Store the correct guesses in one array/list/set and the wrong guesses in another group.  Then you can just call the count method of whatever structure you use to get the number of wrong guesses.